# datatables refresh not working but recieve correct json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I have an error in my code and can’t figure out, what i did wrong. 
The datatable gets filled correctly and on ajax.refresh the table gets valid json-data, but the table does not reload.

HTML

```
    <table id="monatsabschluss" class="listing">
    <thead class="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Aufgabe</th>
            <th>Status<input type="checkbox" id ="express" ></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Javascript

```
var adat = '20160606';
var kid = 7;
var table = $('#monatsabschluss').DataTable( {
     "paging":   false,
     "info":     false,
     "filter":   false,
     "ordering": false,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/management/bavabrech/fetchjobs",
        "data": function ( d ) {
            d.kid = kid;
            d.adat = adat;
        },
        "dataSrc": "data",
    },
    "columns": [
                { "data": "description" },
                { "data": "status",  className: 'statusCol' },
            ],
});
setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload( null, false ); 
}, 5000 );
```

Json

```
  {"sEcho":1,
   "success":true,
   "iTotalRecords":0,
   "iTotalDisplayRecords":0,
   "aaData":    
       [{"description":"Erstellen Rentendaten",
         "status":3,"id":"1"},
        {"description":"Pr\u00fcfliste erstellen",
         "status":4,"id":"2"},
        {"description":"TEXT","status":"","id":"out_2"}]}
```

HTML-Output from the initial Datatable-loading

```
<table class="listing dataTable no-footer" id="monatsabschluss"
role="grid" style="width: 800px;">
<thead class="header">
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
            style="width: 469px;">Aufgabe</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled statusCol" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
            style="width: 269px;">Status<input type="checkbox" id="express">
   </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="">
    <tr role="row" class="maStatusRunning">
        <td>Erstellen Rentendaten</td>
        <td class=" statusCol">Wird ausgeführt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="maStatusComplete">
        <td>Prüfliste erstellen</td>
        <td class=" statusCol">Erledigt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td>TEXT</td>
        <td class=" statusCol"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am using Datatable 1.10.7, i do not get any error messages.

Comment: no error messages is usually caused by, the number of columns in result and in jquery and html may differ, wont through any error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have installed all your code and dug deeper into the problem. Your issue is with your serverSide property. When that is on true, the client expects you to mirror the draw property send to the server so he know that the response he got is for the request he sent (see https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). I also saw that you are using deprecated property names in your response (aaData etc....). You have to change those, so he recognizes your draw property.

That is how the response looks on my side and how it works in my example with your code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
    "success":true,
    "recordsTotal":0,
    "recordsFiltered":0,
    "draw": <?= (int)$_GET['draw'] ?>,
    "data":
    [
        {"description":"Erstellen Rentendaten", "status":3,"id":"1"},
        {"description":"Pr\u00fcfliste erstellen", "status":4,"id":"2"},
        {"description":"TEXT","status":"","id":"out_2"}
    ]
}
```

I have added mirroring the draw property (you can see that in the request url) and renamed aaData to data, iTotalRecords to recordsTotal, iTotalDisplayRecords to recordsFiltered and removed iEcho

Comment: Thank you. You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your example yet, but I can tell a few javascript errors you have.

First of all your data function definition is wrong

```
"data": function ( d ) {
    d.kid = kid,
    d.adat = adat
},
```

The function body is no valid Javascript.
Then there are trailing commas that not every browser likes and that are invalid for json

```
"dataSrc": "data",
{ "data": "status",  className: 'statusCol' },
```

and at the end of your table defintion after the columns part. Do you use an IDE? It should highlight those occurences.

I would start putting a debugger call into your data method so you can track down what happens in there.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I fixed the data function part. The datatables loads correctly on page load, only the refresh does not work. On refresh the table asks for the new data, gets the JSON i posted , but does not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code. The most important thing to remember: always have defined all columns that come with AJAX, hide them via API.
Second thing, do not mix datatables 1.X and 2.X code. It appears to me, that your column definition is for version 2.X, wheras rest of the code is version 1.X

So:

1. Your columns definition is wrong. You're missing one column

   "aaData": [
       { ""mData"": "description" },
       { ""mData"": "status"},
       { "sClass": "statusCol" }
   ],

If you would like to hide column, use bVisible parameter

{ "sName":"id", "sTitle":"Foo", "sClass":"center", "sWidth":"10%", "bSortable":"false", "bVisible": false },

2. I would also change the table html markup to

thead

```
 <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Aufgabe</th>
        <th>Status<input type="checkbox" id="express"></th>
    </tr>
```

tbody

```
  <tr>
        <td colspan="3">No data yet</td>
    </tr>
```

It's always good practive, to use iniutComplete, to see if everything was ok:

```
"fnInitComplete": function (){
    console.log("Init done");
},
```

And the last thing: if you have would like to have extra content inside TD cells, use cell custom renderer.

```
{
    "mRender" : function(data, type, row){
        var sb = [];
        sb.push('<div class="test' + data + '" title="' + row[2] + '">&nbsp;</div>');
        return sb.join();
    }
},
```